# Node JS - Test strategies for C++ plugins

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, debugging, tdd

I've written one or two native `C++` modules for `Node JS`, but always tend to write tests for the modules in `Javascript`. Is this a valid test strategy, or are there better ways to test (and perhaps also, debug) native module code?

Answer (score 1):

Purist will probably say it's "integration" test, not "unit" test. But I personally don't mind. Actually as your module *will* be used from JS, it makes sense to test this aspect too, and if all your tests are done this way, then you test the JS->C++ call really thoroughly.

So I think this is valid strategy. If it is also sufficiently fast (the JS->C++ testing suite overhead being like under 1 second), I would stay with it.

If the JS testing suite is slow, I would reconsider it, and add pure C++ unit testing with some C++ framework (calling the C++ part of public API of the module).

(I personally tried https://github.com/unittest-cpp/unittest-cpp as first one, and stick with it, as I love both the syntax and "complexity" of it, builds fast, no dependencies, and when I'm in "warm" mode with everything previously compiled, doing small C++ change and re-running tests usually takes about 0.5s to compile + run (~hundreds of simple tests) + display result).

If you do this, you should still have some integration tests on JS side to verify the module works also when called from JS, not just in C++.

If you are asking how to compile+run pure C++ separately from JS: depends on your environment setup, I use separate IDE to work with C++ sources. Which allows me also to debug C++ natively of course.